# Consider the following linear operation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

$T: (C^1([0,1]),||.||_u) \rightarrow (C([0,1]),||.||_u)$ , $T(f)=f'$

Let $Gr(T)=\{(x,Tx);x\in X\}$.

To show that $T$ is not bounded consider $ f_n(x)= \frac{Sin(n x)}{n}$.

Thus $T(f_n)$ is not converges so is not bounded.but whether $Gr(T)$ is closed?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260924/how-is-it-that-the-derivative-operator-is-a-closed-linear-operator

Comment: Thanks....but I can not to show that Gr(T) is closed....

Comment: Not convergent does not imply not bounded in general

Comment: yes...but for this question is true...

Comment: might the fundamental theorem of calculus help here? This would mean to consider the inverse operator in a way. (btw: sorry for my first comment, i didnt read the answers there good enuff.)

Comment: Is $\|\cdot \|_u$ the supremum norm?